# Cant build Android after installing react-native-screenshot-prevent React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, screenshot

After adding this package I can't run android any more I followed all the instructions and added all commands but Im still getting error:
`Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081`
and

````
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.```
````

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the first part of Android manual installation instruction:

1. Open up `android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainActivity.java`

```
Add import com.killserver.screenshotprev.RNPreventScreenshotPackage; to the imports at the top of the file
```

```
Add new RNPreventScreenshotPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method
```

Just ignoring this instruction resolved the problem.